# whay is android studio reporting"URI IS NOT REGISTERED"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, github

**So I've given Android Studio a try, because I really like Resharper and noticed that the IDE had some of their functionality built into it. Having now download sourcecode from github, I added a new layout file and wanted to change the existing default  example layout, and I got an "URI is not registered" error on the following line**
this is image
[this image from the code how i can fix it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxfDV.png)

Comment: You probably don't have the required libraries defined the `build.gradle` file!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! We'll be able to help you a lot more if you include your code in your message. See [Creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information.

Comment: this is the code      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TelecineActivity

Comment: when  i create a new projet i don't get "URI not registered" and "is not allowed here" but when open existing project i got this errors